# How to identify shower taps, or how to disassemble them?

Tags: shower, faucet

How can I identify which make & model of shower taps this is?

[image: Shower taps]

This is so I can try to look up assembly instructions

...or maybe you can help me guess how to fix it instead.

Family emergency here. My naughty 6 year old son has managed to break the power adjustment tap (the one on the left). Luckily it's broken in a switched off state, and I'm quite worried if I fiddle too much it might get stuck switched on. The tap on the left still turns. It turns easily over a normal range of rotation for adjusting the power, but also turns more stiffly in either direction beyond that. It also wobbles in and out a bit. To be honest I'm not sure if any of that was happening before, or due to being broken. In any case turning is now no longer turning the shower on.

How do I disassemble the taps? e.g. to remove the tap on the left and see what's behind it?

Comment: what did they brake ? the knob ?, and now you have the valve sticking out. They could have not broken the valve, but still deserve to be grounded.

Comment: Nothing *appears* broken. It's just no longer switching the show on somehow. I guess he twisted it too far one way or another, but hard to be sure what he did.

Comment: You said the left one, not the temperature regulating right one ?

Comment: The cap is either just sticked in (with a snap), so it can be pulled out, or it has a small hex screw on it, still ground them.

Comment: The plastic (yes it is plastic) inside might be worn or thorn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the black cap in the front.

[image: cap]

There is a screw inside.

Unscrew and pull the cap.

Inspect for damages inside.

Bring to plumbing store to get replacement.

Comment: Yes that worked. Quite difficult prise off that cap, but it had screw behind there just as you said. I undid that and pulled off the tap. So that is the correct answer to the "how to disassemble" part of my question. ..... As for the ultimate solution, I feel a bit stupid, but turns out that tap wasn't broken. As I fiddled it started dribbling a little bit, and then I realised the 6 year old had put some heavy kinks in the shower hose (in a way which wasn't obvious) and that was what was shutting of the water flow :-)

Comment: The destroyers .........